# SAS - Format Sum

Tags: sas

I'm printing my dataset and have formatted certain variables so that they include commas.  The comma format is working for the data; however, it's not the sum totals are not printing with commas.  How do I correct this?

```
proc print data=states4 noobs; 
title 'State Information';
format population comma10.;
format roadLength comma7.;
sum avgRain roadLength population; 
run;
```

Comment: Probably a format is not wide enough. Try to change `comma10.` to e.g. `comma16.`.

Comment: Is your log error and warning free?